# Error adding image inside table cell HTML

Tags: html, image

My image's link reference is break. But the image and the html file are in the same folder. And I think that this code is correct:

```
<td><img src="test.jpg" alt="" border=3 height=100 width=300></img></th>
```

This error occurs when I try to run my web application using eclipse, but I created a simple html file in  the desktop and put the image there too, then it runs perfectly. Both codes are the same.

Code:

```
{{define "content"}}
```

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td><img src="test.jpg" alt="" border=3 height=100 width=300 /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

{{end}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are adding that by saving normal HTML file from desktop, it will work. But in other case, Code has to be as per its standard rule. And you were missing some. Please see below the correct way:

```
<td>
   <img src="test.jpg" alt="" border=3 height=100 width=300 />
</td>
```

Also let us know if there is any path related issues.

Comment: It does not work :/. Both files are in this path: /SimpleWebApplication/tmpl

Comment: try giving "~" relative path. or let us know what error are you getting

Comment: This is the error: Could not forward request for /teste.jpg any further.

Comment: what is your filename that you are calling, because in src you have called test.jpg and error is for different file i.e "teste.jpg". I suggest you to check your file name properly

Comment: Sorry, I just mistyped it wrong here. It is "test.jpg"

Comment: inspect your img path from the inspect element and start removing one by one folder, and Check at what level you are visible to view the image. I m sure the issue is with the path. Or else can you give us more information about your code in detail

Comment: I will try this. And I will post my code in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60970/discussion-between-murilo-and-saba).

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with your code. You have tags open, but using the wrong closing tag. Try this:

```
<td><img src="test.jpg" alt="" border=3 height=100 width=300 /></td>
```

Also, it seems you are using HTML4 - very old.
Once you have it working, I suggest removing the border, height and width attributes and use CSS instead.